# Perron's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reading Wielandt's Proof of Perron's Theorem. In general, he constructs a Collatz-Wielandt formula.
Let $A$ a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with positive coefficients, and
$$
f:\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}^*\right)^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}^*, f(x)=\max _{1 \leq i \leq n} \frac{(A x)_i}{x_i}
$$
We can show that $f$ will have minimum value $f(u$) on $(\mathbb{R^*_+})^n$. After that, we need to prove that, $u$ will be an eigenvector of $A$ and $f(u)$ will be an eigenvalue of $A$. But i get stuck with this problem. Here is my attempt
In order to that $u$ and $f(u)$ will be an eigenvector and an eigenvalue respectively, I need to prove that $Au=f(u).u$
First, we will compute our LHS
$$Au=\begin{pmatrix} 
a_{11}u_1+a_{12}u_2+...+a_{1n}u_n\\
a_{21}u_1+a_{22}u_2+...+a_{22}u_n\\
...
\\
a_{n1}u_1+a_{n2}u_2+...+a_{n2}u_n 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Second, we will compute RHS
$$f(u).u=\displaystyle \max_{1\le i\le n} \dfrac{(Au)_i}{u_i} \begin{pmatrix}u_1\\
u_2 \\
...\\
u_n\end{pmatrix}$$
In order to prove $Au = f(u) = u$. First, I need to prove that
$$\displaystyle \max_{1\le i \le n} \dfrac{(Au)i}{u_i}.u_1 = a_{11}u_1 +a_{12}u_2+....+a_{1n}u_n $$
$(\ge):$ We have
$$\displaystyle \max_{1\le i \le n} \dfrac{(Au)i}{u_i}.u_1 \ge \dfrac{(Au)_1}{u_1}.u_1=(Au)_1=a_{11}u_1 +a_{12}u_2+....+a_{1n}u_n$$
$(\le):$ We have
$$\displaystyle \max_{1\le i \le n} \dfrac{(Au)i}{u_i}.u_1 \le \displaystyle \max_{1\le i \le n} \dfrac{(Ax)i}{x_i}.u_1  \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x \in (\mathbb {R^*_+})^n $$
Here, we need to choose the suitable $x \in (\mathbb {R^*_+})^n$ to reach our target. But i don't know how to choose the suitable value of $x$. Can you help me to complete my solution?